# How can I get R to format diff(x) as rows?

Tags: r

I would like the output of the code below to express diff(x) of a series of numbers in rows, not columns. It currently calculates diff(x) of the rows of a data frame, which is what I want, so the values are correct but they are formatted in columns. This is some example code that generates diff(x) of some series of numbers:

```
x <- c(19, 26, 39)
y <- c(34, 47, 51)
z <- c(45,50,60)
B <- data.frame(x, y, z)
B
f1 = function(x){return(diff(x))}
apply(B,1,f1)

>[,1] [,2] [,3]
y   15   21   12
z   11    3    9

#this seems to give diff(x) as columns
#want as rows, i.e. the transpose:

15 11
21 3
12 9
```

Many thanks

Comment: Just transpose: `t(apply(B,1, diff))`?

Comment: Thank you! This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
Bout <- B[-1]- B[-ncol(B)]
```

such that

```
> Bout
   y  z
1 15 11
2 21  3
3 12  9
```

or

```
Bout <- t(diff(t(B)))
```

such that

```
> Bout
      y  z
[1,] 15 11
[2,] 21  3
[3,] 12  9
```

Comment: @Abigail575 For the second approach, the output is a matrix. If you want it as a data frame, you can use `Bout <- data.frame(t(diff(t(B))))`

Comment: @Abigail575 You are welcome! If you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it, thanks.